# Sql query update error in values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Hello guys I have an error in this query and again I cant Figure out what is wrong? i cant find the error. I know this is a simple code but Can you guys please help me in solving this

I got an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where testid=4 and qnid=1' at line 1

```
$query = "update question set question='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['question'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',optiona='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',optionb='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionb'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',optionc='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionc'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',optiond='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiond'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',correctanswer='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',marks='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['marks'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',audiopath=" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['AudioPath'],ENT_QUOTES) . " where testid=" . $_SESSION['testqn'] . " and qnid=" . $_REQUEST['qnid'] . " ;";
    if (!@executeQuery($query))
        $_GLOBALS['message'] = mysql_error();
    else
        $_GLOBALS['message'] = "Question is updated Successfully.";
}
```

Thank for those who will answer

Comment: You are using `@` before executeQuery. This will supress the warning/error. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: the insert already work sir. I just got really confuse. I need both Update and insert

Comment: removing the @ doesnt solve anything ~_~ same error

Comment: Insert is already working. Now i Have Update issue ~_~ I cant solve what is missing there...

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need. You are missing quotes. Looks like you also have an extra semi-colon there.

```
audiopath='" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['AudioPath'],ENT_QUOTES) . "' where testid='" . $_SESSION['testqn'] . "' and qnid='" . $_REQUEST['qnid'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your app more secure I would use PDO extensions http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension